# Passing data between frames with Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, forms, frames

I've setup a simple example at http://ryanmalin.co.uk/frames/

If you press "add" it will paste the form data from the left frame into the right frame.

When I change the right frames URL to that of another domain Firebug throws an error and it doesn't work. The error shown is:

> Error: Permission denied to access property 'document'

Is it possible to copy data from one pre-filled form on my domain to a form on another domain using frames/javascript?

I believe it is an anti-spam measure built into browsers or websites but if possible I need to get around it. To send customer orders through my parcel delivery company I have been copying over each address field one by one between two browser tabs - now that orders are increasing I need to speed this process up, however the courier doesn't yet have a way of sending all of the days order details at once.

I can write the PHP needed to grab the order details for the left frame but don't want to waste time if its impossible to do what Im after.

Many Thanks :)

Comment: You are not allowed to communicate with frames which are on a different domain through javascript, you will need to use a parse through with PHP

Answer (score 4):

See the ["Same Origin Policy"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) for a description of how inter frame security works.  In a nutshell, there is very little communication allowed between frames on a different domain for security reasons.  You cannot make any direct Javascript calls between frames on different domains.

HTML5 has a new messaging system that can safely communicate data (not direct JS calls) between cooperating frames in different domains.  See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage) and [here](http://ajaxian.com/archives/cross-window-messaging-with-html-5-postmessage) for a description of how the HTML5 messaging works.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. It's a deliberate browser restriction for security.