# How to pass value from left frame to right frame in frameset

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

```
<div>
    <iframe scr="page1.php">Left</iframe>
</div>

<div>
    <iframe scr="page2.php">right</iframe>
</div>
```

The result after running **page1.php** on the left frame is `idArr= array(25, 30, 42);`, then i would like to pass the first element on idArr to **page2.php** on the right frame.

In this case, SESSION is not really suitable

Comment: ehmmm this is not possible.see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7170582/passing-data-between-frames-with-javascript

Comment: On the server or in the browser? Btw your code shows iframes, not a frameset...

Comment: @Tim Sure it's possible.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas you can't send the output of one iframe to another iframe, at least if never seen it and never heard of it .You have to save the information created by page1 somewhere and then get it in the second frame (page2) or something. What did you had in mind?

Comment: Same origin policy is not violated in this example.

Comment: @Tim In JavaScript, the iframes have access to each others stuff. They can communicate normally.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to give both frames access to the parent document using `parent.document`

It will be easiest if you give both your iframes an ID:

```
<div>
    <iframe id="frame1" scr="page1.php">Left</iframe>
</div>

<div>
    <iframe id="frame2" scr="page2.php">right</iframe>
</div>
```

From the main parent page, I'd then have a script:

```
frame1 = document.getElementById('frame1');
frame2 = document.getElementById('frame2');
function setFrameArray(frame, array){
    frame.idArr = array;
}
```

From the child iframes, then, you can just call:

```
parent.setFrameArray(parent.frame1, [25,30,42]);
```